# Exporting a Logic Pro 9 Project to FCPX/Premiere Pro with all files kept the same

Tags: audio, final-cut-pro

Is it possible to transfer all the audio files from logic pro to a video editing program so that they are all in the correct place and each file is separate?

I want it so it looks like it does in logic but I can place video upon it.

**Sorry if this is in the incorrect section of stack exchange but I do not know where to to place it.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two major formats for exporting audio files en masse: OMF and AAF. Logic can do both, but it would appear - http://forums.creativecow.net/thread/8/1127487 - that FCP doesn't natively support either one. For a one-time project, the free trial of [Boris Transfer FCP](http://www.borisfx.com/AAF/) should be able to handle AAF. For long-term though, unless you have Boris or [Automatic Duck](http://www.automaticduck.com/products/pifcp/) already, you'd probably be better off exporting All Tracks as Audio Files, and bringing in them one-by-one. This [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HpLPxwcnHx8) walks you through the process of AAF, OMF, or Audio File export.